# I imported pygame through terminal, but the python shell says that it doesn't know a module named pygame. I use a mac

Tags: python, pygame

I want to use pygames mouse functions, but i cant get it to work. In terminal, i used `pip install pygame`. It said that the module was already installed. I decided to import pygame in the shell to test it. but it returned

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/Users/GAMEKNIGHT7/Desktop/genius 
hour/chineseCheckersAI.py", line 13, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

What happened??

Comment: Do you have 2 versions of Python?

Comment: No, i started coding when python 3.5 came out.

Comment: The terminal says:Requirement already satisfied: pygame in /Users/......./.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.9.4)

Comment: Run python --version in the terminal, to see if your running 2 versions of python, python 3.7 and python ?.?

Comment: What is the output of import sys; print(sys.path); in your python terminal and is the package installed to any directory listed in this output?